# Custom Timepicker to update as you type

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to create a custom time picker. I want the time (00:00) to change as you click the buttons but can't seem to get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11856/

I also want it to default to 'pm' but change if they click 'am'. Can anyone help. Is there a better way to go about doing it other than something like:

```
 if($scope.time.length == 1 || $scope.time.length == 2){
    $scope.hour = $scope.time;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't 100% about what you want. If you want to refresh after each click or only when the date is done.

Anyway, in your function addNumber, this lane have to be done before the if. Because if you do it after after, the if condition will check the siez before you increment the variable.

```
$scope.time += number;
```

There is what i've done.

https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11865/

Comment: Thanks, I want it to refresh after each click basically... so if it is set to the default '00:00' and they click '1' I want it to say '01:00' then they click '2' it would be '12:00' and so on

Comment: There is the update then : https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11868/ The difference here is the fact that you do'nt need to update only when the siez is 4, you update after each click, and the view do the same